# jQuery: Add Class to Element's Child

Tags: jquery, html, css

**HTML:**

```
<div class="cell-container">
  <img src="image.png" class="thumbnail" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hover {
  background-color: silver;
}
.hover-image {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".cell-container").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
});

$(".cell-container").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});
```

Basically I want the div `cell-container` to have a highlighted background onmouseover. But also add a border to the `<img>` contained within. How can I achieve this?

Comment: change the CSS property you used `border-color` to just: `border` and take a look at the answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just do this in CSS?

```
div.cell-container:hover {
  background-color: silver;
}

div.cell-container:hover img.thumbnail {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I forgot you could apply :hover in CSS haha. Thanks.

Comment: +1 What an excellent way to do it with only CSS. Why didint I think of that?

Answer (score 4):

btw [$.hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) provides both mouseover and mouseout.

```
$(".cell-container").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
    $(this).children('img').addClass('hover-image');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
    $(this).children('img').removeClass('hover-image');
});
```

Comment: No need to use `$(this)` twice.

Answer (score 2):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/izoxip/edit#javascript,html,live)**

```
$(".cell-container").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("hover").find('img').addClass('hover-image');
});

$(".cell-container").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hover").find('img').removeClass('hover-image');
});
```

And you have to change your CSS:

```
.hover-image {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".cell-container").hover(function(){ // using hover for shorter syntax
    $(this)
        .addClass("hover") // add hover class on mouseover
        .find("img") // select the child image
            .addClass("hover-image"); // add hover class
}, function(){ // mouseout function
    $(this)
        .removeClass("hover") // remove hover class
        .find("img") // select the child image again
            .removeClass("hover-image"); // remove hover class
});
```

More on `hover()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Comment: +1 for a fair competition ;) (and a correct example, of course)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
.cell-container:hover
{
  background-color: silver;
}

.cell-container:hover img
{
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

just css.

If you are just adding styling classes you should always make sure that what you are trying to achieve is not possible in css (it usually is).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".cell-container").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
    $(this).children("img").addClass("img-hover");
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
    $(this).children("img").removeClass("img-hover");
  }
);



.hover-image {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```